# pandas strings in cells to new rows

Tags: python, string, pandas

I've been trying to find something that would use pandas to create a dataframe from a csv I have. The problem is that my second column is a string of dates followed by notes. I can't really use it in this format. I've been looking for a post with a similar format but I can't seem to find one. I'm sure the answer is more obvious than I think it is but I'm too close to the problem now so any help would be much appreciated.

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
Order          Notes

123456    "[oct-10-28] some stuff about the client
           [oct-15-18] some more notes about the client
           [nov-19-18] made some changes to account"

789456    "[oct-1-18] idk why it doesn't work
           [oct-20-18] client is mad"
```

what I need as an output is this:

```
Order     Notes

123456  oct-10-28
123456  oct-15-18 
123456  nov-19-18 
789456  oct-1-18
789456  oct-20-18
```

*** Edit

I tried the solutions offered by piRSquared and Wen and they all had the exact same result so I'm adding some additional info to see if you can help. I think maybe I have a formatting issue or something.

```
base_ops_df.head(5)
```

[image]

*sorry, not sure how to get that output here easily

import re

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[o, d] for o, n in zip(*map(base_ops_df_test.get, ['Order', 'Notes']))
     for d in re.findall('\[([\w-]+)\]', n)],
    columns=base_ops_df_test.columns
)
```

[image]

Thanks for all of your help on this, I'm totally stumped right now.

Comment: what have you tried? Can you show how data looks inside pandas?

Comment: Hi mad_, I made an edit to my post to share some more info. Thanks for taking a look for me!

Answer (score 4):

#### Comprehension and `re.findall`

```
import re

pd.DataFrame(
    [[o, d] for o, n in zip(*map(df.get, ['Order', 'Notes']))
     for d in re.findall('\[([\w-]+)\]', n)],
    columns=df.columns
)

    Order      Notes
0  123456  oct-10-28
1  123456  oct-15-18
2  123456  nov-19-18
3  789456   oct-1-18
4  789456  oct-20-18
```

---

#### `itertools.chain` and more

```
from itertools import chain

n = df.Notes.str.findall('\[([\w-]+)\]')
pd.DataFrame(
    [*zip(df.Order.repeat(n.str.len()), chain(*n))],
    columns=df.columns
)
```

---

#### Setup

```
Notes = ["""[oct-10-28] some stuff about the client
[oct-15-18] some more notes about the client
[nov-19-18] made some changes to account
""",
"""[oct-1-18] idk why it doesn't work
[oct-20-18] client is mad"""]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Order=[123456, 789456],
    Notes=Notes
), columns=['Order', 'Notes'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I posted an edit to my original post with an update, I'm still having some trouble and I'm not sure why. I'm also curious why you used an asterisk with the map method. I can't find documentation on how that works and I'm newish to python. I'm transitioning from using R

Answer (score 4):

Using `extractall`

```
df.set_index('Order').Notes.str.extractall('\[([\w-]+)\]').reset_index('match',drop=True)
Out[405]: 
                0
Order            
123456  oct-10-28
123456  oct-15-18
123456  nov-19-18
789456   oct-1-18
789456  oct-20-18
```

Comment: @piRSquared that is right Sir, I am learning the regex step by step :-)

Comment: I didn't mean to delete that /facepalm

Comment: @piRSquared no worry I got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If any of you can solve the issue I'm having with using pandas, I still want to understand how it works and figure out a solution. However, for the sake of meeting deadlines I decided to convert my dataframe to a numpy array, do my work, and then convert it back. Here's how I did it:

```
base_ops_df.Order = pd.Series(base_ops_df.Order, dtype='category')
base_ops_df.Notes = pd.Series(base_ops_df.Notes, dtype='str')

base_ops_array = np.array(base_ops_df)
the_big_list = []

for row in base_ops_array:
    rows = str(row)
    row_string = rows.split(' ')
    for element in row_string:
        if "[" in element:
            list_dates = [row[0], element]
            the_big_list.append(list_dates)

operations_dates = pd.DataFrame(the_big_list, columns=['Related_Order', 'Dates'])
operations_date = operations_dates[~operations_dates['Dates'].astype(str).str.contains('\n')]
crap_to_replace = ["'", "[", "[["]
operations_date.Dates = operations_date.Dates.str.replace("'", "")
operations_date.Dates = operations_date.Dates.str.replace("[", "")

operations_date.head(100)
```

This clearly isn't nearly as elegant of a solution, but it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try split and slicing

```
a = "[oct-10-28] some stuff about the client"
b = a.split(sep=']')[0][1:]
print(b)
```

Comment: How does it directly answers OP's question?